# return list of int using case when then MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, switch-statement, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select * from table where columnType in( case when TRUE then (1,2) end );
```

This query is giving syntax error  `Invalid argument types for function 'IFF': (BOOLEAN, ROW(NUMBER(1,0), NUMBER(1,0)), NULL)`.

It is working fine if I am using a single integer to return in then statement i.e

```
select * from table where columnType in( case when TRUE then (1) end );
```

How can I return a list of integers in a case statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the "CASE" condition first and then the "IN" condition.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
<case condition> AND columnType in (1,2) OR
<case condition> AND columnType in (1)
```

Comment: It's a sample query @Chrille. I do need to use the `case` in the actual query. That's why looking for a way to achieve the same in case/when/then.

Answer (score 0):

This is an other option to do it using `REGEXP`:

```
select *
from table 
where columnType REGEXP ( case when TRUE then '1|2' end );
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RaSwsNLF)